# R if condition in row, assign value to new column - lappy/ifelse/for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, lapply

I have been looking for a decent answer for quite sometime, in Python a for loop would solved this in a matter of seconds.
I have got about 100K URL, I m trying to group them based on a specific string that they contain, I have seen many similar example to mine however nothing is quite what I need.
The most popular answer is using a ifelse, which doesn't work in my case as I m using a long list, if there is a "if" option I will take it(as oppose to ifelse)

Reproducible code

```
list<-c("birthday","anniv")
myData <-data.frame(URL = c("/birthday/promoid:654654","/birthday/products/","/anniversary","/anniversary/?type=gifts","/celebration","/celebration"), PageView=1:6*515)
```

then I want to create a new column called "occasion", so I can group the URLs and expect the below

```
myData$occasion<-ifelse(grepl("birthday", myData$URL),"birthday",
                    ifelse(grepl("anniv", myData$URL),"anniv",
                           ifelse(grepl("anniv", myData$URL),"anniv","NA")

                           )
                    )

URL PageView occasion
1 /birthday/promoid:654654      515 birthday
2      /birthday/products/     1030 birthday
3             /anniversary     1545    anniv
4 /anniversary/?type=gifts     2060    anniv
5             /celebration     2575       NA
6             /celebration     3090       NA
```

Here I have used nested ifelse, however it is unfeasible as the list of keyword will reach 10K
I have looked into lapply but haven't succeeded as I have simply no idea how to assign the value to a new column

```
lapply(list, function(list) 
        sub(paste0(".*",list,".*"),list, myData$URL, ignore.case = TRUE)
)
```

as this give me a list

```
myData$Occasion<- lapply(list, function(list) 
        sub(paste0(".*",list,".*"),list, myData$URL, ignore.case = TRUE)
)
```

*Edit: I m looking for a solution that doesn't involve a for loop as I have always been told that this is very inefficient tin R. I am thinking lapply however I haven't been able to succeed

Comment: instead of nested if-elses, why not just two separate grep statements?

`myData$tag <- NA
myData$tag[grep("birthday", myData$URL)] <- "birthday"
myData$tag[grep("anni", myData$URL)] <- "anniversary"`

Comment: BTW: *really* bad idea to name a variable `list`. I suggest something like `tags` or `taglist` or even `lst`, but not `list`, the name of an oft-used base function in R.

Comment: @tcash21 that's ok if you have only a couple of tags, I have 10k, so won't do that 10,000 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of nested if-elses, why not just two separate `grep` statements? Does this perform fast enough?

```
myData$tag <- NA 
myData$tag[grep("birthday", myData$URL)] <- "birthday" 
myData$tag[grep("anni", myData$URL)] <- "anniversary"
```

Or, for a little flexibility and code-golf, collectively:

```
for (s in mytags) myData$tag[grepl(s,myData$URL)] <- s
```

Comment: `for (s in mytags) myData$tag[grepl(s,myData$URL)] <- s`

Comment: ooo nice for an arbitrary # of tags!

Comment: Yeah, I really try to pay homage to my undergrad CS professors by thinking *"0, 1, or any"*.

Comment: @r2evans I guess that will have to do for now, however I am looking at a solution that doesn't use for loop as it is usually slow and most R users will usually cringe when seeing this. Does anyone know how to make tis work with apply/Lappy? I think that would e a lot neater

Comment: ??? Guillaume, what are you talking about? First, especially in a use like this, there is nothing you can do that is faster than this `for` loop, and *when used properly*, there is little-to-no difference in performance between `for` and `*apply` functions. Second, it makes **no sense** to try to `lapply` over a vector of patterns. The time to think about `*apply` is when you are doing something to each element/column of a list/data.frame and need to capture the output. In this case, the `for` loop is used entirely for its side-effect.

Comment: ... and the purpose for my suggested `for` loop is to keep you from typing an unrolled loop for every element of a vector of patterns. If you want to avoid `for` and type all of those in manually, that's all you, the decision has nothing to do with performance, efficiency, or elegance.

Comment: @r2evans I am taking your words for it, I was always told that forloop are not efficient to use in R so always staying away from them. I m trying to make your answer the best answer but unable to do so as (I believe) is due to the fact it is a comment

Comment: I understand. At one point there were speed problems with `for` loops (in comparison with `*apply` functions), but that was fixed several years ago, yet the opinion persists. (However, neither of them hold a candle to the speed improvement that *vectorized math* can do. An `*apply` can be just as inefficient as a `for` loop in comparison to a single vectorized operation.) You cannot accept a comment, and adding that as a new answer doesn't really add much to this one, so just accept this one. I think my comment is high/upvoted enough that it will stay visible.